# Python retrieve last key in a nested dictionary that keeps updating

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary like this:

```
game =

{
    "player": "Michael"
    "round": 4,
    "score": [
        {
            "1st": 342346,
            "2nd": 345423,
        },
        {
            "1st": 12411,
            "2nd": 90296,
        },
        {
            "1st": 20172,
            "2nd": 21279,
        },
        {
            "1st": 62348,
            "2nd": 32662,
        }
    ],
    "player": "Sarah"
    "round": 3,
    "score": [
        {
            "1st": 6446,
            "2nd": 5423,
        },
        {
            "1st": 311,
            "2nd": 1596,
        },
        {
            "1st": 6472,
            "2nd": 2119,
        },
    ],
}
```

where the rounds keep updating. I know how to retrieve value from this dict with:

```
game['score'][0]['1st']
game['score'][0]['2nd']
```

but I need to retrieve always the last one, which keeps updating depending on the rounds played.
In this case, the last one would be:

```
1st = 62348
2nd = 32662
```

Comment: This dictionary has duplicate keys. Are you aware that only the last one would retain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lats on is based on the value of 'round', plz try this...

```
l = [ x for x in game['score'][game['round']-1].items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

While your dictionary has duplicate keys (which makes it incorrect), assuming that the score is correct (list), you can use negative indexing to get the item at the end:

```
game['score'][-1]['1st']
game['score'][-1]['2nd']
```